# Subtraction of a variable from a variable in the next row if certain conditions are met

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to subtract a variable from a variable in the next row if certain conditions are met.
Consider the following data frame:

```
time <- c(12, 14, 16, 10, NA, 18)
type <- c("morning", "noon", "evening", "morning", "noon", "evening")
data <- data.frame(time, type)
```

As I have 4000 rows in my data, I need a loop with two changing values (for two rows of interest). I have not tried to implement the loop yet as I struggle to select a specific row and a specific value in a column. (But I would very much appreciate suggestions how to include the loop as well!)
So far, the code looks like this:

```
if(data[which(data[row1, "type"] =="morning")] & data[which(data[row2, "type"] == "noon")]) | data[which(data[row1, "type"] =="noon")] & data[which(data[row2, "type"] == "evening")]) {
data[row2, "difference"] <- data[row2, "time"] - data[row1, "time"] 
}  else{
  data[row2, “difference"] <- NA
}
```

So I want to subtract the value from time in row1 from time in row2 and store the result in the variable “difference” in row2.  However, the values should only be subtracted if one of the two conditions are met.

Comment: Your example data doesn't work. You missed the `c` at the start of the vectors, and you have smart quotes. Also `cbind` will create a matrix not a `data.frame`. Try `time <- c(12, 14, 16, 10, NA, 18)` and `type <- c("morning", "noon", "evening", "morning", "noon", "evening")` and `data <- data.frame(time, type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` is the workhorse function for basic differences between 2 values.
You can calculate all the differences in one go, and then overwrite those that aren't in your desired comparisons with `NA`

```
data$prevtype <- c(NA, head(data$type,-1)) 
data$difference <- c(NA, diff(data$time))
data$difference[!(
  (data$prevtype == "morning" & data$type == "noon") |
  (data$prevtype == "noon"    & data$type == "evening")
)] <- NA
data$prevtype <- NULL

#  time    type difference
#1   12 morning         NA
#2   14    noon          2
#3   16 evening          2
#4   10 morning         NA
#5   NA    noon         NA
#6   18 evening         NA
```

Data used:

```
time <- c(12, 14, 16, 10, NA, 18)
type <- c("morning", "noon", "evening", "morning", "noon", "evening")
data <- data.frame(time, type, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works perfectly. Thanks also for your brief explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this

```
transform(
  data,
  difference = ave(time, cumsum(type == "morning"), FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
)
```

which gives

```
  time    type difference
1   12 morning         NA
2   14    noon          2
3   16 evening          2
4   10 morning         NA
5   NA    noon         NA
6   18 evening         NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(time = c(12, 14, 16, 10, NA, 18), type = c("morning", 
"noon", "evening", "morning", "noon", "evening")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately I do not understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option.  Lag function will allow retrieval of previous row's value.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
time <- c(12, 14, 16, 10, NA, 18)
type <- c("morning", "noon", "evening", "morning", "noon", "evening")
data <- data.table(time, type)
data[,difference :=
 ifelse(((time > lag(time)) & (type == "noon") & (lag(type) == "morning")),time - lag(time),NA)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Your suggestions works well, except for that fact that only one condition is included, e.g., only the lag between morning and noon gets calucalted but not between noon and evening.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the elegant code by ThomasIsCoding to `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(type == 'morning')) %>%
  mutate(difference = c(NA, diff(time))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-grp)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
   time type    difference
  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1    12 morning         NA
2    14 noon             2
3    16 evening          2
4    10 morning         NA
5    NA noon            NA
6    18 evening         NA
```